# java Matcher delete some character

Tags: java, regex

I have a following String "Mo-Sa 10:00-20:00". I want get two groups. First group is Mo-Sa and the second group is 10:00-20:00. The first group can be contains only one day, for example "Mo". So i thought i need following regular expression: `([MTWFSouehrao-]{2,5}) ([0-9:-]{11})`. 
My Java Code is:

```
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("([MTWFSouehrao-]{2,5}) ([0-9:-]{11})").matcher("Mo-Sa 10:00-20:00");
if (match.matches() && match.find(1) && match.find(2)) {
     String s = match.group(0); // -Sa 10:00-20:00
     String s1 = match.group(1); // -Sa
     String s2 = match.group(2); // 10:00-20:00
}
```

Why is the first group "-Sa" and not "Mo-Sa"? It does not make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking `find(int i)` in your condition.

This is likely not what you're expecting: it doesn't test whether the groups at index `i` are found, but moves the cursor at index `i` after resetting the matcher.

All conditions are `true`, and since you're using `&&`, all are evaluated.

Therefore, `match.find(2)` is the last evaluated, so your grouping starts at index `2` of your input.

If you just remove those conditions, your output will be what you expect:

```
if (match.matches()) {
...
```

**Output**

```
Mo-Sa 10:00-20:00
Mo-Sa
10:00-20:00
```

**Note**

In order to test whether a group index is matched, you can use:

- `Matcher#groupCount()` to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s on non-existing group indices
- `Matcher.group(int i)` and compare to `null`, to find whether a specific group has fulfilled its condition. This will require either `find` or `matches` to be invoked first.
- Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Comment: yes you are right. The find method change the cursor position.